# Objects not being disposed when using child lifetimescopes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, autofac

I have an ASP.NET 5 application which still uses EF6 and I register my services with Autofac as follows:

```
builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>()
    .As(typeof(IUnitOfWork))
    .InstancePerDependency();

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
    .Where(t => t.FullName.StartsWith("MyApp") && t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .InstancePerDependency();
```

Then in controllers I'm doing:

```
//Save object of type SomeObject
using (var scope = itemScope.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    var someService = itemScope.Resolve<ISomeService>();
    var savedObject = await someService.SaveAsync(objectToSave);
}
```

The above runs in a loop in a background thread.

Originally I was not using child scopes. But then, using the diagnostic tools, I noticed that the `SomeObject` references are increasing and not being removed from the data context.

So I decided to add child scopes to have new instances every time. But this doesn't the problem. It stays as is.

If I'm using a child scope why does this happen, and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are still using itemScope to resolve the service. Note that `scope` was not used inside the `using` at all.

```
//Save object of type SomeObject
using (var scope = itemScope.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
  //var someService = itemScope.Resolve<ISomeService>();
    var someService = scope.Resolve<ISomeService>();
    var savedObject = await someService.SaveAsync(objectToSave);
}
```